# AlarmManager executing task after an interval of minutes instead of an interval of a day

Tags: android

Given that the AlarmManager.setInexactRepeating() function works only with APIs less than API 19, I used the AlarmManager.setExact() function for APIs 19 upwards and used a broadcast receiver to perform the required task then call the alarm function again to make it a repeating alarm. The alarm works but it doesn't respect the intended repeat interval. I did some research to see what others did and I'm at my wit's end.

I created a class to handle the alarm as shown below:

```
public class AlarmStart {

public AlarmStart() {
}

public void startAlarm(Context context) {
    // Start service
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19) {
        Intent service = new Intent(context, MyService.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, service, 0);

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
                AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,
                pendingIntent);
    }
    else {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyBroadcastReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24, pendingIntent);
    }

    // Enable receiver when device boots
    ComponentName receiver = new ComponentName(context, BootReceiver.class);
    PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();

    pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(receiver,
            PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
            PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
}
```

Below is the code in the BroadcastReceiver class which makes a call to the service to be executed at intervals (which works well), then makes another call to the startAlarm() function:

```
public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

AlarmStart alarmStart = new AlarmStart();

public MyBroadcastReceiver() {
}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // Start service
    Intent service = new Intent(context, MyService.class);
    context.startService(service);

    //Schedule next alarm
    alarmStart.startAlarm(context);
}
```

In AndroidManifest.xml, I set the enabled and exported attributes of the broadcast receiver to true.

Please can someone tell me what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have messed up the start time.

replace

```
alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24, pendingIntent);
```

with

```
alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()+(1000 * 60 * 60 * 24), pendingIntent);
```

The same thing with

```
alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
```

replace with

```
alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()+AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
```

The problem was that you have launched the alarm in wrong moment of time.

Comment: I also changed setInexactRepeating() to just set() for api levels < 19 and used a broadcast receiver and it got accurate. Thank you very much